# How to recompile javacv and opencv

Tags: java, c++, opencv, compiler-construction, javacv

Always I get the same error when I use javacv :

`Fatal access exception`

I read some topics in the [Discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/javacv)   where the solution suggested is to recompile everything with the same C++ compiler .

I use windows 7 , and I have a little bit idea about C++

So Can any one help me how Can I recompile both javacv an opencv ? 
Thanks

Comment: what is `boost::zip_iterator` ( I'am newer to c++ )

Comment: Sorry, wrong question! Never mind :-S